# VideoView working on MainActivity but doesnt work on my Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Below is the code provided, I'm trying to shift this video view into my Home Page (Fragment java class). I've seen people using get Methods but I just keep getting errors. The video view works fine on the MainActivity java class.

---

Main Activity Java Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView video;
    String video_url = "https://www.daddyandco.com.my/Daddy-Co-Bartender-Promo.mp4";
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pd.show();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_url);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    }
}
```

---

Home Fragment Java Class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Fragment` init `View view = inflate....`.

Use the below code Its works for you

```
 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    VideoView video;
    String video_url = "https://www.daddyandco.com.my/Daddy-Co-Bartender-Promo.mp4";
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        video = view.findViewById(R.id.video);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
        pd.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pd.show();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_url);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(view.getContext());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        return view;
    }
}
```